# BXSlider within wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, bxslider

So I am not wanting to use the plugin because I want control over this slider. I am having issues with it not utilising the styles and js files. I am calling them in through the functions files and the files are situated in the CSS and JS folders within the theme.

Here is the function for calling in the js with the jquery.

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bxslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.js', array(), '1.8.2', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Similarly here is the css (All works aside from the bxslider)

```
function theme_styles () {
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('social', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/webfonts/ss-social.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('social', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.bxslider.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

I have placed the slider directly into front-page.php like the following:

```
        <ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>





  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: true,
  auto: true,
  useCSS: true,
  easing: 'ease-in',
  pager: false
});
});
</script>
```

I am also wanting to show posts instead of hard coded images so here is the php I am using for that:

```
<?php
$content = '<ul class="bxslider">';
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'your_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full', true);
        $content .= '<li><a href="';
        $content .= get_permalink();
        $content .= '"><img src="';
        $content .= $thumb_url[0];
        $content .= '" alt="';
        $content .= get_the_title();
        $content .= '" /></a></li>';
    endwhile;
$content .= '</ul>';
echo $content;
?>
```

I just need an eye to see what appears to be failing here?

Comment: is there any error? PHP or JavaScript error? what is front-page.php?

Comment: front-page.php is the landing page for Wordpress, it is part of the WordPress Template Hierarchy. There are no errors within the php but I am getting an error in the console log for the BXslider ' Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(index):164 (anonymous function)' On this line... 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it looks like bxslider js is getting included before jQuery.

To solve this dependency problem, WordPress wp_enqueue_script function has a parameter called $deps, so try following code:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bxslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.2', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

See for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: The strange thing is I have called JQuery into the header file to test and still not playing ball...

Comment: Can you confirm the order of js inclusion by looking into html source?

Comment: Looking at the page source, the JQuery is coming in after all the style sheets but your above function to call in the bxslider isnt showing at all - the JQuery is me including it manually in the heade and not via functions, removed the manul one but still nothing showing JQuery is being included

Comment: Are you calling wp_head & wp_footer functions in your theme?

Comment: Sure am as mentioned before the CSS function is working perfectly fine.